# Как залить фон button частично?

Tags: android

Привет! Нужно вводить число от 0 до 1 в edittext, а после заливать цветом часть фона button в соответствии с введенным числом( т.е. ввели 0.25 - заливаем четверть кнопки)

В списке аттрибутов ничего подобного, к сожалению, нет

Comment: Как вариант можно в битмапе рисовать прямоугольник с нужным заполнением и натягивать в бэкграунд.

Comment: Почитай [эту](http://megadarja.blogspot.ru/2011/03/android-xml-drawables.html) статью, может, поможет.

Comment: @600, Как вы себе это представляете? Т.е. как эти 0.25 поверхности должны заливаться: сверу вниз, справа налево. под углом, в горошек рандомно по всей поверхности, или ещё как-то?

Comment: @lsillarionov слева направо)

Comment: Т.е. вам нужна кнопка - индикатор загрузки? Подойдет ProgressBar под прозрачной кнопкой?

Comment: @lsillarionov вроде да, смутно представляю как это реализовать правда

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Предлагаю свой вариант решения вопроса - создание кастомной кнопки с необходимой функцией. Сразу [ссылка GitHub](https://github.com/pavlofff/ProgressButton) на небольшой сэмпл, как это все работает и картинка :

[image: screenshot]

Реализация проста и состоит из менее десятка строчек - подрисовывать на кнопку дополнительный слой с шириной, которую мы можем установить сами:

"Мучить" будем очень модную сейчас material-кнопку (`AppCompatButton`) из последней `support.v7 - 22.1` , но то же самое можно проделать с любым виджетом, это не принципиально.
Собственно сам класс кастомной кнопки **ProgressButton.java**:

```
public class ProgressButton extends AppCompatButton {
 private float mRatio;
 private int mColor = Color.GREEN;

 public ProgressButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
 }

 public ProgressButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
 }

 public ProgressButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
 }

 void init(){

 }

 public void setRatio (float ratio){
    mRatio = ratio;
    invalidate();
 }

 public void setColor (int color){
    mColor = color;
    invalidate();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable fill = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_btn_default_mtrl_shape);
    fill.setColorFilter( mColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    fill.setAlpha(128);
    fill.setBounds(0, 0, (int) (getWidth()*mRatio),  getHeight());
    fill.draw(canvas);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
  }
}
```

в качестве дополнительного слоя мы используем тот же xml (`abc_btn_default_mtrl_shape.xml`), что используется и для прорисовки бэкграунда самой кнопки, окрашивая его в собственный цвет, но можно использовать и любой собственный вид при необходимости. Прозрачность устанавливается для того, чтобы эффект нажатия был виден по всей кнопке, а не только на не окрашенной части.

кастомная кнопка реализует методы:

1. `setRatio(float ratio)` - установить процент заполнения фона кнопки - число от 0 до 1.
2. `setColor(Color color)` - установить цвет заливки

Теперь, как это все работает. Простой пример заполняет часть кнопки при нажатии на нее:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 ProgressButton button;
 float ratio;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (ProgressButton) findViewById(R.id.progress_button);

 }

 public void onClicked (View view) {

   button.setRatio(ratio);
   ratio = ratio +0.3f;
   if (ratio >= 1) ratio = 0;
 }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:padding="10dp"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<com.pavlofff.progressbutton.ProgressButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progress_button"
    android:text="progress button"
    android:onClick="onClicked"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [ScaleDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ScaleDrawable.html).

**res/drawable/progress_indicator_shape.xml** - drawable, размеры которого мы будем изменять. Просто зелёный прямоугольник:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#00ff00"/>
</shape>
```

**res/drawable/progress_indicator.xml** - ScaleDrawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress_indicator_shape"
    android:scaleGravity="left"
    android:scaleHeight="0%"
    android:scaleWidth="100%" />
```

layout (основная часть):

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_frame"
        android:background="@drawable/progress_indicator"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

В разметке кнопка завернута в FrameLayout и сделана прозрачной с бэкраундом selectableItemBackground, чтобы сохранить ей обратную связь на нажатие. Можно завернуть два бэкраунда в один LayerListDrawable.

Код:

```
View mButtonFrameView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(...);
    final EditText valueView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.value);
    mButtonFrameView = findViewById(R.id.button_frame);
    View buttonView = findViewById(R.id.button);
    buttonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            float progress = 0;
            try {
                progress = Float.valueOf(valueView.getText().toString());
                if (progress < 0) progress = 0;
                if (progress > 1) progress = 1;
            } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {}
            updateButtonProgress(progress);
        }
    });
    updateButtonProgress(0);
}

void updateButtonProgress(float progress) {
    Drawable background = mButtonFrameView.getBackground(); // ScaleDrawable
    background.setLevel((int)(10000f * progress));
}
```

Comment: Попробовал сегодня этот вариант. При вводе числа в edittext вешает эмулятор наглухо)) genymotion. Вот как должен выглядеть результат, вы бы могли взглянуть?https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByDGeRr7y29SYzBVOG03OUhuVDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Решил использовать прогрессбар, а сверху прозрачную кнопку. Спасибо всем