# Как задать рамку и увеличение кнопки програмно?

Tags: android

Как увеличить `ІmageButton` (scale) и добавить рамку (stroke) при нажатии(в методе `OnClick()`) в классе `MainActivity`?

Comment: Вам нужен эффект увеличения при нажатии или какая задача? С чем связано желание делать именно программно, оформление заранее не определено и должно формироваться в процессе выполнения программы? Опишите задачу более подробно.

Comment: У меня есть более 70 иконок(ІmageButton) на GridLayout , сами понимаете как они будут выглядеть на маленьких дисплеях , ефект увеличение нужен для того чтобы пользователь был уверен что он сделал правильный выбор, если это так он должен нажать LongClick. Писать для каждой кнопки <selector>, у меня нет особого желания потому и хочу решить эту задачу программно.

Comment: В смысле, для каждой кнопки писать селектор, они разные должны быть у всех кнопок? Обычно пишется один селектор и назначается всем нужным кнопкам. Насчет программно - лучше всего сделать кастомный `View` с наследованием от того же `ImageView`, чтобы реализовал нужные действия, так как если добираться до стандартного извне, там будут заморочки с позиционированием (будет смещаться вниз-вправо, а не от центра).[Пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423285/1773450) кастомного `view`

Comment: **Спасибо Вам за ответ.** У меня каждая иконка(ІmageButton) имеет разный фон(background), как можно сделать один для всех selector который будет увеличивать и добавлять рамку? Если ставить фон в параметр src: картинка выглядит неправильно. Подскажите пожалуйста!