# Можно ли сделать такой background через shape?

Tags: android

в качестве background для TextView можно использовать градиент

list_grad.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="@color/gradient_start"
    android:endColor="@color/gradient_end"
    android:angle="-270" /> 
</shape>
```

...

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ranking_order"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_grad"
    />
```

можно ли через shape сделать такой background ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**добавил:**

Можно ли задать сложную фигуру для ProgressBar, как на рисунке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю через Canvas можно сделать чтото похожее. Если сначала отрисовать прямоугольник прогресса, а потом по маске вырезать фигуру. Но не будет ли это слишком тяжелой операцией?

Comment: Вам что то вроде [этого надо](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423285/177345)? тут одним шейпом не обойтись тогда

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо за пример

Comment: @pavlofff, можно ли задать сложную фигуру для ProgressBar? (расширил вопрос)

Comment: да, можно, смотрите вы просто делаете к примеру VIew элемент. И у вас обычный Progress Bar. Потом делаете transparent форму в виде машинки к примеру это ImageView растягиваете её по весь View элемент сверху, получается что прогресс бар будет работать также, но сверху будет закрываться машинкой которая в центре прозрачная. Получите такой эффект как хотите, и да, это очень простая операция.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, спасибо за ответ. А можно добиться прозрачного фона? Мне нужно разместить этот элемент на другом изображении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В теории можно:

```
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#08a303" />
        <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="320dp">
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FFF" />
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="20dp" android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]