# Двухцветный Button

Tags: android, button, background

Проблема такова. Нужно получить background у button как на этой картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом нужно оставить возможность регулировать степень заполнения черным цветом из кода.

Как лучше это сделать?

Comment: откровенный костыль - ImageView с Bitmap построенным руками (двойным циклом).

Comment: еще один костыль - забить на все и сделать `ProgressBar`

Comment: А как быть со всякими pressed и прочими стейтами которые в разметке обычно задаются?

Comment: Можете сделать кастомный `View`, который будет содержать по факту 2 `Button` с разными цваетами.

Comment: вам нужнен [такой эффект](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423285/177345)?

Comment: @pavlofff, лучшее решение с onDraw(), а то хрень советуют

Comment: @pavlofff Да это прямо то что надо, спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Фон кнопки устанавливаете белый, а вместо картинки используете черный цвет, потом с помощью `paddingRigth` регулируете отступ с права. Примерно вот так:

```
    mImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int width = mImageButton.getWidth();
            int procent = 50;
            mImageButton.setPadding(0, 0, width*procent/100, 0);
        }
    });
```

Разметка:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:src="@color/colorBlack"/>
```